# Segmentation fault when trying to access properly allocated array

Tags: c, malloc, c-strings

I'm trying to read a CSV file and am writing a function to parse a line of data into an array of strings, which dynamically changes the size of the array and updates `size` and `str_size` accordingly. I have written a properly-working function called `find_key()` to locate the `fseek()` location of the line in question. I'm coming across a problem that I think relates to the allocation of the string array: I get a segmentation fault on the line at the bottom of the while loop, where it reads `data[data_count][str_pos] = curr`. The program breaks when I try to access `data[0][0]`, even though as far as I can tell I've allocated memory properly. Any help would be appreciated!

```
/**
 * @brief Get a row from the provided CSV file by first item. Dynamically
 *        allocated memory to data array
 * 
 * @param file
 * @param key First item of row
 * @param data Array of strings containing data
 * @param size Size of array
 * @param str_size Size of strings in array
 * @return 0 if successful, -1 if the row cannot be found, or 1 otherwise
 */
int csv_get_row(FILE *file, char *key, char **data, size_t *size, size_t *str_size) {
    if(!file || !key) return 1;

    /* Get the position of the beginning of the line starting with the key */
    long pos = find_key(file, key);
    if(pos == -1) return -1;
    fseek(file, pos, SEEK_SET);

    /* If these parameters aren't useful values, assign default values */
    if(*size < 1) *size = DEFAULT_ARRAY_SIZE;
    if(*str_size < 1) *str_size = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;

    /* If the memory for the array hasn't been allocated, do so now */
    if(!data) data = (char**) malloc(*size * *str_size);

    /* Get characters one-by-one, keeping track of the current amount of elements and the current buffer position */
    size_t data_count = 0;
    size_t str_pos = 0;
    char curr;
    while(fscanf(file, "%c", &curr)) {
        if(data_count >= *size) data = (char**) realloc(data, (*size *= 2) * *str_size);
        if(str_pos >= *str_size) data = (char**) realloc(data, *size * (*str_size *= 2));

        if(curr == ',') {
            data[data_count][str_pos] = '\0';
            data_count++;
            str_pos = 0;
            continue;
        }

        if(curr == '\n') {
            data[data_count][str_pos] = '\0';
            data_count++;
            break;
        }

        data[data_count][str_pos] = curr;
        str_pos++;
    }

    /* Resize the array to fit */
    *size = data_count;
    data = (char**) realloc(data, *size * *str_size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(fscanf(file, "%c", &curr))` can result in an infinite loop because `EOF` is a non-zero (i.e. true) value. The loop should be `while(fscanf(file, "%c", &curr) == 1)`

Comment: As for the memory allocation, we're going to need to see how you call that function. See [mcve].

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause of your problem, but note that any changes you make to your `data` double-pointer in the function will be **lost forever** when that function returns. That pointer is passed to the function from the calling module *by value* and changes your function makes will *not* be passed back to the caller.

Comment: IMO, your code is ***waaaay*** too complex for something that reads a line from a CSV file and splits it into fields.  First get your code to read lines.  Then use a separate function that splits each line into fields.  Then take those fields and fill in your array. You can easily test each of those steps and get them working. What you have written is a mashup of all of those into one, and it's too complex to get working and impossible to test step-by-step.  And because you're reading `char`-by-`char` with an `fseek()` involved, it's also **S-L-O-W**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that `*size` starts at 1. You set `data_count` to 0. Then, in the first iteration,
you do not have `data_count >= *size`, so you don't `realloc()`. You increment `data_count`
to 1, though, so in the next iteration, you grow the `data` buffer to 2.

So, at this point, `data` has length 2 and `data_count` is 1.

Let's then say we do not go into the first `if` statement but the second.
There, you increment `data_count` to two. You then access `data[data_count]`, which is one
past the last element. That is a problem.

That might be the problem you see at the end of the `while`-loop, but it is far from the
only problem. Whenever you `malloc()` or `realloc()` `data`, you are invalidating the pointer the caller
has, because you might be freeing the memory at the original location. You never give him
a pointer to the new data back; all the newly allocated data will be leaked when you
return from the function, and the caller must *never* access `data` after the call, lest
he wants a segfault.